# How to check if array without looping Mustache JS?

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is there a way to check the existence of an array without looping? I found that using {{#foos}}{{/foos}} loops through the array. I need to first check if the data is present though.

Something like this:

```
{{if foos}}
    <ul>
        {{#foos}}
            <li>{{foo}}</li>
        {{/foos}}
    </ul>
{{/if}}
{{^foos}}
    No foos!
{{/foos}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after `{{#foos.length}}`

```js
var template = `
{{#foos.length}}
  <ul>
    {{#foos}}
      <li>{{foo}}</li>
    {{/foos}}
  </ul>
{{/foos.length}}
{{^foos.length}}
    <p>No foos!</p>
{{/foos.length}}`

const div = document.getElementById("result")

// with content
div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", Mustache.render(template, {
  foos: [{
    foo: 'Alpha'
  }, {
    foo: "Beta"
  }, {
    foo: "Gamma"
  }]
}));

// without
div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", Mustache.render(template, {
  foos: []
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I don't see `.length` anywhere in the [documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). How did you come across this?